# C programming: Using a variable inside another variable name (not sure of the technical term)

Tags: c, variables

I don't know what the technical term is but I would like to do following:

```
int var_a;
int var_b;
int var_c;
char letter;

letter = 'b';
printf("%d", var_'letter');
```

However, I don't want to use if statements. Can I directly sub in the rest of the variable name with the variable char so that the computer would see "var_b"?

Comment: No, you cannot do this.

Comment: A term for this is 'dynamic variable name', which C does not support.

Comment: hmm, thanks, the exact term I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

Not possible. You could try using an array and indexing it like this:

```
vars[letter - 'a'];
```

Where `vars[0]` would correspond to your `var_a` and so on.

Comment: I was going to post something similar. It might be better to declare an `enum` to use for the index rather than using character literals. E.g., `enum my_vars { A, B, C }; vars[A];`

Comment: thanks, i was hoping dynamic vars were allowed in C, guess not.